# DataTables loads the data but the buttons and sorting don't function as expected in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I have an Angular 4 project that I am trying to display my data in a table format using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) library. I am able to work with the hardcoded data that are in their websites. I have all the buttons (copy, print, excel) working fine. However, when I try to show my data that I grab from SQL database using service, I am able to display data in the table but none of the buttons work. I even have `No data available in table` text in the table.

My html code:

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Submited Date/Time</th>
        <th>Submisson Status</th>
        <th>Extra</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let p of participants">
      <td>{{ p.firstName }} {{ p.middleName }} {{ p.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.zip }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.crreatedDateTime | date:'short' }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.projectStatus }}</td>
      <td>Ask</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And My component.ts is:

```
import { ParticipantService } from './../../_services/participant.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-participant-list-demo',
  templateUrl: './participant-list-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./participant-list-demo.component.css']
})
export class ParticipantListDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  participants: any[];

  constructor(
    private participantService: ParticipantService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadStyles();
    this.loadParticipants();
  }

  loadParticipants() {
    this.participantService.getAll().subscribe(participants => {
      this.participants = participants;
    });
  }

  loadStyles() {
    $(function () {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
    });
  }
}
```

I tried loading the participants first using `'zone` it didn't work either. How can I plug my dynamic data to the DataTables so that I can use its buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the styles of the datatables and the actual list of participants are inside the `ngOnInit` method. Which means they both are loading at the same time. Temporarily, I can use `setTimeOut()` function to make sure the participants loads first then styles of the datatables are next with a perhaps 300 ms time period. But again, this is not a perfect solution. I am still looking for a better approach.